# jQuery mobile misses css effects on vclick/fastclick

Tags: javascript, css, mobile-safari, jquery-mobile

As anyone who has used jqm on an android/iOS device knows, the 300ms delay can cause headaches.
Thankfully there are a variety of solutions -- use fastclick.js, "vlick" method, and other options.

However, when you apply this solutions, the css effects don't follow through. 
Here's a demo:
http://nischenspringer.de/jquery/fastclick/demo.html 
(from https://github.com/Plaputta/jquery.event.special.fastclick)

If you click around the demo on a computer, you see hover and click css effects. However, if you click from an iOS device, you only see those effects when you hold on the button for the 300ms (i assume). If you click quickly, the application will respond and do the action, but you will not see any css changes!

Any ideas on how to fix this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working example: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/w6XHJ/)**

All you have to do is set jQuery Mobile config variable: **[buttonMarkup.hoverDelay](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/api/globalconfig.html)**

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
});
```

But be careful, mobileinit **`MUST`** be initialized before jQuery Mobile, like this:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
        $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
    });
</script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

Comment: amazing. thanks so much! (i was looking in all the wrong places... css js files... etc)

Answer (score 0):

If its version >= 1.4 try

<li class='ui-btn' />

or else try

<li data-role='button'/>